# supremum and expectation of a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $X_{t}$ a right continuous $\textbf{F}_{t}$ martingale and $\textbf{F}_{t}$ satisfying the usual condition

Show that  $ \sup_{t\geq 0}\textbf{E}(X^{2}_{t})<\infty$.

I know that $X^{2}_{t}$ is a submartingale and by Doob's inequality  we have $\textbf{E}(\sup_{s\leq t}X^{2}_{s}) \leq 4\textbf{E}(X^{2}_{t})$

but i don't  know how  continue. Some help would be appreciated

Comment: There has to be some additional hypothesis.  What are the "usual conditions"?  I meant you could set $\mathcal F_t = \mathcal F$, and have $X_t = X$ where $X$ is your favourite function which is not in $L^2$.

Comment: this is exactly the formulated problem

Comment: I agree with Stephen. I don't think this is true without additional hypotheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that this does **not** hold. @Stephen Montgomery-Smith already mentioned the "trivial" counterexample $$X_t := X, \qquad t \geq 0$$ for some $X \notin L^2$. Another counterexample is a one-dimensional Brownian motion $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$; it is a martingale with continuous sample paths and satisfies $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)=t$, hence $$\sup_{t \geq 0} \mathbb{E}(X_t^2) = \infty.$$ (In both cases, the usual hypotheses on the filtration are satisfied.)

Comment: ok, i understand